# Bootstrap dropdown menu missing on one page but appears on another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I've added Bootstrap dropdown menu in my rails app. The problem is that the menu appears in one of my page and is missing on another, but the menu is still there when you hover over. How can I fix this, so the menu appears on every page?

```
                        <li><div class="dropdown" style="padding:10px; display: block; position: static;">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">個人</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                             <li><%= link_to "聯絡", 'http://eedd.herokuapp.com/contact' %></li>
                             <li><%= link_to "編輯資料", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                             <li><%= link_to "登出", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                         </ul></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code in the Bootstrap documentation is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       href="#">
        Dropdown
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <!-- links -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Seems like you have an extra div in there? If that is not the problem then you would need to examine what else is different in-between the two pages, as it is likely something else is interfering with the CSS.

Comment: You are right, but because I am already within a <ul class="nav pull-right">, so I added an extra div in there. I am not sure if thats right way to do it, but it seems to work now. Except that it shows different colors at local and on heroku.

Comment: Different colors in environments is either down to one not being updated (different code) or caching in your browser. The other possibility is that your production environment is not configured the same as your development environment.

Comment: I think it's the browsers, since I git push to Github 1st and then push to heroku master from github.

Comment: So is the original menu problem fixed now? You should try clearing your browser cache

Comment: I've discovered that I added another scaffold css when I try to add scaffold category, and some how that new css is causing this. Now that I have removed this file and it is fine. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.